# Please help me - algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus

It is considered  positive integers $a, b, c$ with $a^2+b^2+a+b=abc$. Prove that $c\in\{3;4\}$.

Comment: How about $a=10$ , $b=1$  ?

Comment: $c$ must be an integer.

Comment: @Michael. Sorry, yes, I didn't have my coffee yet...:)